# Javascript Regex abbreviation detection/ Count words in sentence?

Tags: javascript, regex, abbreviation

I am using a regex in order to split up a text into its sentences. This is my Code:

```
elem.replace(/([.?!])\s+(?=[A-Z])/g, "$1|").split("|");
```

Problem is that e.g. an abbreviation like. "Appl. No." or "Doc." are recognized as a sentence.
Is there any method to prevent such behavior?

Does anyone know e.g. how to modify the regex to split only if a sentence contains more than 1 word?

```js
var text= "hello eveyone. This is a text, with a Abbreviation. Appl. No. is 2134."

result=text.replace(/([.?!])\s+(?=[A-Z])/g, "$1|").split("|");

/*
Result is "hello eveyone., This is a text, with a Abbreviation., Appl., No., is 2134."
But it should be:
Result is "hello eveyone., This is a text, with a Abbreviation., Appl. No. is 2134."
*/
```

Comment: Please click edit then `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve] with input and expected output

Comment: Saw this question yesterday too. No, there is no way to determine or extract sentences or abbreviations or anything language related using regex alone.